# Re-enabling csrutil prevents mac from booting after a new apf image mounted [BigSurOS]

Tags: macos, big-sur, sip

#### Question

How to re-enable csrutil and csrutil authenticated-root and get the mac to load?

#### Problem

After having mounted a new boot Volume with a small modification to the folder `/usr/lib` I am unable to enable csrutil and csrutil authenticated-root, since the Mac won't boot.

I tried ***undoing*** the process (described below in this case leaving the `/usr/lib` as it was originally removing the symlink I've added) and then enabling csrutil in recovery mode but still Mac System won't boot.

So currently the only way the system boots is if  csrutil and csrutil authenticated-root are disabled.

#### Context

It all started when an application was crashing (under MacOS BigSur) because it could not found a file `/usr/lib/libcrypto.dylib`, my first idea was to add a symlink there to the library as it was a file of openssl. But it turns out this location is protected by csrutil and csrutil authenticated-root.

1. I reboot on recovery mode and disabled both.

Yet still I was unable to add a symlink in that location until I've found that actually the system volume is read-only. And the only way to have a symlink there was to create a new image mount it in a new location, add the symlink and then make the image readonly and ready to be the new volume boot by following this [guide](https://twitter.com/enhancedscurry/status/1275454103900971012)

1. `sudo mount -o nobrowse -t apfs /dev/diskNsM /path/to/mntpoint`
2. make needed modifications in my case: add a symlink to `/path/to/mntpoint/usr/lib/`
3. `sudo bless --folder /path/to/mntpoint/System/Library/CoreServices --bootefi --create-snapshot`
4. Restart

It worked!, I've launched the application and no more crashing.

But i felt empty since going so far just to allow loading an app that I think I won't even keep, and as I've found the source code (Python) i was able to find the line of code that pointed to the protected `/usr/lib` and just redirected it to where the file was and also the problem was solved, so I want to have csrutil fully enabled.

Comment: Can you boot to Recovery? Have you tried reinstalling the OS?

Comment: I can boot to recovery, And Im looking for a solution that does not involve system reinstall.

Comment: Why? Reinstalling the OS won't erase your data. (And you will have a backup anyway.)

Comment: Time mostly, it will require also reinstall all the apps ...

Comment: Just reinstalling the OS should not affect your existing apps. The OS and your data are on two separate volumes.